# how to get specific data from list?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've a table information on the list() here tblRole is a table name form database. In the list the list count is 2. now I want to get the every list row data. I don't know how to do this can anyone help me please.

```
Dim dbContext As New HREntitiesModel()
Dim searchResult As New List(Of TblUser)
Dim roleSearch As New List(Of TblRole)
Using dbContext
      roleSearch = (From result In dbContext.TblRoles
                        Where result.FldSysName.Contains(newSearchString)
                        Select result).ToList()
      For Each item In roleSearch
              searchResult = (From result In dbContext.TblUsers
                             Where result.FldRoleIDRef = item.FldRoleID AndAlso result.FldUserDeletedDTG Is Nothing
                             Select result).ToList()
      Next
End Using
```

Comment: Can you make code here? Then I will help you.

Comment: Delete above comment and add same in your post. It will be more clear for us to understand :)

Comment: update this code in your question. that will be much more readable.

Comment: @shibly I have updated your question with the code from comment. you can check it or add it yourself.

Comment: @Shibly, Put your code here.

Comment: @Shibly, Update your question using above comment code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach (tblRole tblRow in  List<tblRole>) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(tblRow.ColumnName);
}
```

:)

Comment: The problme is my List<tblRole> count is 2 so if I run this code only show the first rows information.

Comment: No. This is for each loop in you list. Try it buddy. it is 100% working for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have list use simple forach:

```
foreach (int item in  List) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
using (dbContext)
{ 
    roleSearchGuid = (from result in dbContext.TblRoleswhere result.FldSysName.Contains(newSearchString)result); 
    dynamic count = roleSearchGuid.Count; 
    foreach (tblRole tmp in roleSearchGuid) 
    { 

       searchResult = (from result in dbContext.TblUserswhere result.FldRoleIDRef == tmp.FldRoleID && result.FldUserDeletedDTG == nullresult).ToList(); 
    } 
}
```